# is there any situation that we dont have any primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

i recently read an article about creating secure php login system which will guide step by step and now this question camed to me why in this article there is no primary key in login_attempts table.
the article which i talked about:
[this article](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL#Steps)

```
Create the "login_attempts" table:
CREATE TABLE `secure_login`.`login_attempts` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

please go to step 4

> Create a table to store login attempts.

then the question is realy clear just as title is.is there any situation that we dont have any primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, but you need to atleast add a *non-unique* `INDEX` on column `User_ID` to improve the performance when querying on the table.

```
ALTER TABLE login_attempts ADD INDEX idx_userID (User_ID)
```

- [When To Use Indexes In MySQL](http://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases)
- [MySQL Query Optimization](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377652)

Comment: But in this case there isn't really any reason to skip the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Well the point of the primary key is to provide some value in which you can index data on unique values for performance. In situations like the one you have there may be possibilities that neither column is unique. Supposing your logon is multithreaded there is a chance, although small, that numerous users have the same `time` of logon, putting a primary key on that would obviously deny someone or cause fault. If you put primary key on the `user_id` then you'd be denying the same user multiple attempts.

In other situations, such as creating many-to-many relationships with a table between two others for foreign keys you would do something similar.

*Disclaimer* I'm sure someone can provide a stronger explaination but this is my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

A primary key is not necessary by default - it depends if eache row of the table must be identifiable, e.g. when it's used as foreign key in other tables.

In that specific case I'd say the `user_id` is enough - but it should be indexed as you most likely want to select using that column.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few cases where a primary key isn't necessary. Imagine if you'd want to delete a specific row, how can you delete the right one? Two login attempts at the same time would insert two identical rows.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys are a Database Admininstration tool which has become a pillar in keeping consistant information in database registries.. However, they can be dispensed of as long as there is a clear and safe mechanism for keeping the desired information consistence  in DB tables. At DB level you could dispose of a primary key. But on a Logical level, you must have a mechanism which will help you differentiate over different registries, that by itself is the pragmatic concept of what a Primary Key is... so basically: If you need having consistant information, you can never dispose of PKs, in a logical level..

In my current job, I became dba for a GPS tracking system, and I came out that all the information is assorted in MySQL. I was given this project 'as is' with close to no documentation and no starting point, but lots of tasks to achieve. My first thought was to scan the DB schema. And I found out that all the tables lacked PKs... weren't even close to following [Database Normalization Basics](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm). It was a relational database without PKs or FKs, but it was operational, bringing service to thousands of GPS devices.

Of course, that db schema is extremely prone to failures, but information is kept mildly consistant by the company, in a really primitive manner..

So... I opted on redoing the DB schema and migrating all the information to a new, Normalized schema based on Auto-Incremental PKs, constrains and integrity triggers, developing a MVC application for handling all that DB data and I'm into quite a challenge: My first ever professional project ever.

As my conclussion for personal experience. Primary Keys are a standard guideline on keeping information consistant, real and organized. You could dispose of them ANYTIME, but using them will save you a lot of completely unnecesary work on both design and implementation.